# AngularJS Select Options selected is not working

Tags: angularjs, html-select

I have Select options being populated from a different JSON and the Selected value to be bound to another JSON. With the below code, the select is populating but its not selecting the current value!. Im definitely sure Im missing something in the select definition. I did search but all of them were related to one object and not two different ones.

HTML:

```
<table class="detailtable"><tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="tdItemLabel">Item</td>
        <td ><input type=text ng-model="currentItem.ItemName"></td>
        <td class="tdItemLabel">Type</td>
        <td>
            <select ng-model='currentItem.Type' data-ng-options='tType.Type for tType in AllItems'></select>
        <td>Qty</td>
        <td >{{currentItem.Quantity}}</td>
    </tr>
    <TR>
        <td class="tdItemLabel">Desc</td>
        <td colspan="5">
            <textarea style='width:100%' rows=6 ng-model='currentItem.ItemDesc'></textarea>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Price</td>
        <td><input type=text ng-model='currentItem.Cost'></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And here is the JSON structure

```
$scope.AllItems = [{Type:"T1",Value:"10"},{Type:"T2",Value:"20"},{Type:"T3",Value:"30"}];
$scope.currentItem = {ItemName:"Picture",Type:"T2",Cost:"200",ItemDesc:"Details of Picture"}
```

Ofcourse Im expecting to use currentItem to update that record back in server.

Comment: To add, its adding the default option as selected while rendering


```<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>```

Comment: Ok I got this working with following code 
```
<select ng-model='currentItem.Type' ><!--ng-options='tType.Type for tType in AllItems'-->
                                    <option ng-repeat="tType in AllItems" value='{{tType.Type}}'>{{tType.Type}}</option>
                                </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `data-ng-options` to `ng-options`. For the options, the syntax would be `variable.key as variable.value for variable in list`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did (I Swear, all by myself!). Not sure if this is the **Correct** way!

```
<select ng-model='currentItem.Type' >
   <option ng-repeat="tType in AllItems" value='{{tType.Type}}'>{{tType.Type}}</option>
</select>
```